# Как загружать изображения после полной загрузки страницы сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно загрузить изображения в два блока (`#div_left`, `#div_right`) после полной загрузки страницы сайта.

Comment: Почему не загружать вместе со страницей?

Comment: Фото большие и тормозят загрузку страницы сайта

Comment: Грузят сначала маленькие превьюшки вообще то.

Comment: Да я знаю но мне этот вариант не подходит

Comment: @Muson взгляните на мой ответ либо можно воспользоваться готовым плагином ленивой загрузки, как посоветовал **IonDen**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы так же можете попробовать использовать плагин [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)
Он предназначен для того, чтобы загружать изображения только после того, как пользователь доскроллил до них. В вашем случае, если изображения уже есть в области видимости, они так же начнут загружаться только после того, как загрузился весь DOM и запустился JS.

Answer (score 5):

Вместо `src` напишите что-нибудь вроде `data-src`. Потом, когда надо загрузить изображения, напишите `$('[data-src]').each(changeDataSrcToSrc)`;

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[data-src]').each(changeDataSrcToSrc);
});

function changeDataSrcToSrc(i, e) {
    e.src = $(e).data('src');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hello
<img data-src="//placehold.it/32x20">
<img data-src="//placehold.it/32x40">
<img data-src="//placehold.it/32x50">
world
<img data-src="//placehold.it/32x10">
```

Answer (score 2):

Стандартное решение примерно такое:

**HTML**

```
<img style="display:none;" src="...">
// либо если используете bootstrap
<img class="hidden" src="...">
```

**JS**

```
window.load = function() {
    $('img').show();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего так:

```
$(function() {
  $("#div_left").css('background-image', '/img1.png');
  $("#div_right").css('background-image', '/img2.png');
});
```

Но если надо дождаться загрузки всех картинок на странице и только после этого добавлять фон, то так:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#div_left").css('background-image', '/img1.png');
  $("#div_right").css('background-image', '/img2.png');
});
```

PS: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/document-ready-vs-window-load-vs-window-onload